# What are the semantics of datastore filters on lists and why do you sometimes need two indexes on the same kind (in the same direction)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore entity kind that has a property that is a list of integers. At the moment there is a single entity in the datastore where the property has the value [5, 6]. I have been unable to find much documentation about how queries on list properties work so could anyone explain why I get the following results:

`property = 5 AND property = 6` returns the entity. I would expect this because there are items in the list matching both conditions.

`property = 6 AND property <=5` throws an error that I am missing the composite index `property(asc), property(asc)` (yes, the same property twice). If I add this weird index I can run the query and get the expected result.

`property <=5 AND property = 6` returns no results. Why does this behave like neither of the first two queries? What is even weirder is that when I add a double index to that property the results change and suddenly I get the expected result returned. I thought adding an index wasn't supposed to change the semantics of the query?

If anyone could explain exactly what the datastore does behind-the-scenes to produce these bizarre results, I would be most grateful.

Comment: it's not a weird, you just tell db to make index of all pairs. or it will be unable to find any results, that's true

Comment: @IgorArtamonov But why does it not find results in one case and say it needs an index in another? They are the same query because `AND` is commutative right?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Also, what does it even mean to have indexed the same field twice?

Comment: in seconds case I guess it tried to use existing index, but it doesn't have enough information

Comment: your field is array, right? say you have following docs `id1: [5,6], id2: [5,6,7]`. One item index will be just: `5 -> (id1, id2), 6 -> (id1, id2), 7 -> (id2)`. but when you're indexing pairs it will be `(5, 6) -> (id1, id2), (5, 7) -> (id2), (6, 7) -> (id2)`

Comment: @IgorArtamonov But if I have a single pair index then I can query with equality as many times as I want (or indeed do that without a pair index so long as there is not inequality condition). Why would that work with out say, a tripple index?

Comment: Because for single equality you have all data in index. Take a look at my example, with single index `5 -> (id1, id2)` you can easily say that for `property == 5` there're two documents, with ids `id1` and `id2`. But this index is not enough if you have to check for two values, because how do you find which of this documents also have `6` also?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov But in your example I also couldn't query for `property = 5 AND property = 6`; on the datastore that is perfectly possible. What is it about equality that makes a double index necessary  and what is it about a double index that makes querying on infinitely many inequalities possible?

Comment: I guess they have a special workaround for equality, because it's comparable cheap to find this using single item index

Comment: You must understand that I'm just guessing, I'm not a developer of the Datastore, so I don't know how it really implemented. I just don't see anything weird in an index of pairs for array, when you're filtering by such pair in your query